# What is the purpose of initialize phase in maven

Tags: maven

Im trying to understand purpose of initialize phase in maven. In documentation its written - initialize build state, e.g. set properties or create directories. Which directories and properties it is referring to and where it is initialized

Thanks for help

Comment: It is for _your_ Pom to hook into -  if you for any reason need anything done at that phase of the build, execute plugins in it

Comment: Ok. Can you give some example that what properties and directories we can initialize

Comment: Maven runs through a number of phases _in order_ which allows you to attach a plug-in at a specific place in the lifecycle.  What then actually happens is entirely up to the plug-in. Some compiles code, some define resources etc.  typically each plug-in can be configured in the Pom.xml file. Maven comes with a default configuration suited for compiling Java. I believe the initialization phase is empty. So find or write a plug-in that does what you need and tell maven to execute it in the appropriate phase.